# Phone code prefix number mvc custom validaton

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations, custom-attributes

I have followed different examples to come up with a custom validator to check a phone number. My number is going into three different fields. I just want to make sure that if the phone number is provided then all three fields should have some thing in them. When i click the submit button, i get the value of the filed that i have applied this attribute to fine. `Now for the other two fields, i am getting the wrong id and due to this, the value is undefined as showing in this image`. What am i doing wrong here? I don't want to move the phone fields out of the student class and into the view model.

[image]

Looks like my issue how i am specifying the other properties

```
[PhoneCodePrefixNumber(FieldOne = "HomePhoneAreaCode", FieldTwo = "HomePhonePrefix", ErrorMessage = "You must enter all three parts of the phone number.")]
```

And if i change ids here per my structure (Student_HomePhoneAreaCode and Student_HomePhonePrefix), then the attribute code throws an error since the ids are wrong this line returns null

`var baseFieldOneInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(FieldOne);`.

The ids as displaying on the page are, the view model has the student class as a property:

1. Student_HomePhoneAreaCode
2. Student_HomePhonePrefix
3. Student_HomePhoneLastFour

Here is the html from the page. if you look at the third input, the ids here are wrong for my two other fields `data-val-phonecodeprefixnumber-fieldone="HomePhoneAreaCode" data-val-phonecodeprefixnumber-fieldtwo="HomePhonePrefix"`.

```
<input class="autoTabElement" data-val="true" data-val-digits="Please input only numbers for area code." data-val-length="Please input 3 numbers for the area code." data-val-length-max="3" data-val-length-min="3" id="Student_HomePhoneAreaCode" maxlength="3" name="Student.HomePhoneAreaCode" style="width:26px;" type="text" value="816" />&nbsp;
<input class="autoTabElement" data-val="true" data-val-digits="Please input only numbers for phone prefix." data-val-length="Please input 3 numbers for the phone prefix." data-val-length-max="3" data-val-length-min="3" id="Student_HomePhonePrefix" maxlength="3" name="Student.HomePhonePrefix" style="width:26px;" type="text" value="525" />&nbsp;
<input class="autoTabElement" data-val="true" data-val-digits="Please input only numbers for phone number." data-val-length="Please input 4 numbers for the phone number." data-val-length-max="4" data-val-length-min="4" data-val-phonecodeprefixnumber="You must enter all three parts of the phone number." data-val-phonecodeprefixnumber-fieldone="HomePhoneAreaCode" data-val-phonecodeprefixnumber-fieldtwo="HomePhonePrefix" id="Student_HomePhoneLastFour" maxlength="4" name="Student.HomePhoneLastFour" style="width:32px;" type="text" value="2201" />
<br /><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Student.HomePhoneAreaCode" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Student.HomePhonePrefix" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Student.HomePhoneLastFour" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Here is the Student class properties. Please note that Student class is added to to view model.

```
[Digits(ErrorMessage = "Please input only numbers for area code.")]
        [StringLength(3, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Please input 3 numbers for the area code.")]
        public string HomePhoneAreaCode { get; set; }


        [Digits(ErrorMessage = "Please input only numbers for phone prefix.")]
        [StringLength(3, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Please input 3 numbers for the phone prefix.")]
        public string HomePhonePrefix { get; set; }


        [Digits(ErrorMessage = "Please input only numbers for phone number.")]
        [StringLength(4, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessage = "Please input 4 numbers for the phone number.")]
        [PhoneCodePrefixNumber(FieldOne = "HomePhoneAreaCode", FieldTwo = "HomePhonePrefix", ErrorMessage = "You must enter all three parts of the phone number.")]
        public string HomePhoneLastFour { get; set; }
```

Here is the attribute code

```
public sealed class PhoneCodePrefixNumberAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        public string FieldOne { get; set; }
        public string FieldTwo { get; set; }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var valThis = (IComparable)value;

            var baseFieldOneInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(FieldOne);
            var valFieldOne = (IComparable)baseFieldOneInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            var baseFieldTwoInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(FieldOne);
            var valFieldTwo = (IComparable)baseFieldTwoInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            ValidationResult result = null;

            if (valThis != null || valFieldOne != null || valFieldTwo != null)
            {
                if (
                    (valThis != null && (valFieldOne == null || valFieldTwo == null)) ||
                    (valFieldOne != null && (valThis == null || valFieldTwo == null)) ||
                    (valFieldTwo != null && (valThis == null || valFieldOne == null))
                    )
                {
                    result = new ValidationResult(base.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata,
            ControllerContext context)
        {
            var errorMessage = this.FormatErrorMessage(metadata.DisplayName);
            var compareRule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
            compareRule.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
            compareRule.ValidationType = "phonecodeprefixnumber";
            compareRule.ValidationParameters.Add("fieldone", FieldOne);
            compareRule.ValidationParameters.Add("fieldtwo", FieldTwo);
            yield return compareRule; 
        }
    }
```

and the client side validation code

```
//PhoneCodePrefixNumber Client Validation Rules
            $.validator.addMethod("phonecodeprefixnumber", function (value, element, params) {
                // debugger;
                var fieldone = params.split(",")[0];
                var fieldtwo = params.split(",")[1];

                if (params == undefined || params == null || params.length == 0 ||
                    value == undefined || value == null || value.length == 0 ||
                    fieldone == undefined || fieldone == null || fieldone.length == 0 ||
                    fieldtwo == undefined || fieldtwo == null || fieldtwo.length == 0){
                    return true;
                }

                var valueFieldOne = $(fieldone).val();
                var valueFieldTwo = $(fieldtwo).val();
                alert(value + "|" + fieldone + "=" + valueFieldOne + "|" + fieldtwo + "=" + valueFieldTwo);

                if (value == "" && valueFieldOne == "" && valueFieldTwo == "")
                    return true;

                if (value == "" || valueFieldOne == "" || valueFieldTwo == "")
                    return false;

                return true;
            });
            $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("phonecodeprefixnumber", ["fieldone", "fieldtwo"], function (options) {
                options.rules["phonecodeprefixnumber"] = "#" + options.params.fieldone + "," + options.params.fieldtwo;
                options.messages["phonecodeprefixnumber"] = options.message;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated attribute that is working for me...

**Use**

```
[MultiFieldPhone(FieldOne = "PhoneAreaCode", FieldTwo = "PhonePrefix", FieldThree = "PhoneLastFour", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid phone number.")]
public String PhoneAreaCode { get; set; }

[MultiFieldPhone(FieldOne = "PhoneAreaCode", FieldTwo = "PhonePrefix", FieldThree = "PhoneLastFour", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid phone number.")]
public String PhonePrefix { get; set; }

[MultiFieldPhone(FieldOne = "PhoneAreaCode", FieldTwo = "PhonePrefix", FieldThree = "PhoneLastFour", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid phone number.")]
public String PhoneLastFour { get; set; }
```

**RegEx**

```
public const string NumbersOnly = @"^[0-9]+$";

Or for more control you can change the checking and use the following regex

public const string PhoneUs = @"^[2-9]\d{2}[-]\d{3}[-]\d{4}$"; //^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$
```

**Attribute Code**

```
public class MultiFieldPhoneAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        public string FieldOne { get; set; }
        public string FieldTwo { get; set; }
        public string FieldThree { get; set; }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var valThis = value;

            var baseFieldOneInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(FieldOne);
            var valFieldOne = baseFieldOneInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            var baseFieldTwoInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(FieldTwo);
            var valFieldTwo = baseFieldTwoInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            var baseFieldThreeInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(FieldThree);
            var valFieldThree = baseFieldThreeInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            ValidationResult result = null;

            if (valThis != null || valFieldOne != null || valFieldTwo != null || valFieldThree != null)
            {
                var rgx = new Regex(ValidationRegExRules.NumbersOnly);
                if (valFieldOne == null || valFieldTwo == null || valFieldThree == null || valThis == null)
                {
                    result = new ValidationResult(base.ErrorMessage);
                }
                else if (valFieldOne.ToString().Length < 3 || valFieldTwo.ToString().Length < 3 || valFieldThree.ToString().Length < 4)
                {
                    result = new ValidationResult(base.ErrorMessage);
                } else if (!rgx.IsMatch(valFieldOne.ToString()) || !rgx.IsMatch(valFieldTwo.ToString()) ||
                    !rgx.IsMatch(valFieldThree.ToString()))
                {
                    result = new ValidationResult(base.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata,
            ControllerContext context)
        {
            var errorMessage = this.FormatErrorMessage(metadata.DisplayName);
            var compareRule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
            compareRule.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
            compareRule.ValidationType = "multifieldphone";
            compareRule.ValidationParameters.Add("fieldone", FieldOne);
            compareRule.ValidationParameters.Add("fieldtwo", FieldTwo);
            compareRule.ValidationParameters.Add("fieldthree", FieldThree);
            yield return compareRule;
        }
    }
```

**Client Side Code**

```
(function ($) {

    //#endregion MultiFieldPhone Validation Rule

    $.validator.addMethod("multifieldphone", function (value, element, params) {
        var fields = params.split(",");

        var fieldOne = $("#" + fields[0]);
        var fieldTwo = $("#" + fields[1]);
        var fieldThree = $("#" + fields[2]);

        var numbersOnlyRegEx = "^[0-9]+$";

        var isValid = true;
        var i;

        if (value == "" || !value.match(numbersOnlyRegEx)) {
            isValid = false;
        } else {
            if (!jQuery.inArray($(':focus').attr("id"), fields)) {
                for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                    if ($("#" + fields[i]) == null || $("#" + fields[i]).val() == "") {
                        isValid = false;
                    }
                }
            } else if ((fieldOne != null && (fieldOne.val().length < 3 || !fieldOne.val().match(numbersOnlyRegEx))) ||
                (fieldTwo != null && (fieldTwo.val().length < 3 || !fieldTwo.val().match(numbersOnlyRegEx))) ||
                (fieldThree != null && (fieldThree.val().length < 4 || !fieldThree.val().match(numbersOnlyRegEx)))) {
                isValid = false;
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            if (!isValid) {
                if ($("#" + fields[i]) != null && !$("#" + fields[i]).hasClass("input-validation-error")) {
                    $("#" + fields[i]).addClass("input-validation-error");
                }
            } else {
                if ($("#" + fields[i]) != null && $("#" + fields[i]).hasClass("input-validation-error")) {
                    $("#" + fields[i]).removeClass("input-validation-error");
                }
            }
        }

        return isValid;
    });

    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("multifieldphone", ["fieldone", "fieldtwo", "fieldthree"], function (options) {
        options.rules["multifieldphone"] = options.params.fieldone + "," + options.params.fieldtwo + "," + options.params.fieldthree;
        options.messages["multifieldphone"] = options.message;
    });

    //#endregion MultiFieldPhone Validation Rules

}(jQuery));
```